# calculate total avarage Rating php

Tags: php, rating-system

**how to calculate the total average (user) rating**

EXAMPLE: user ratings 20 average 4.3

```
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM rating where to_user_id='".userid."'");
```

**count**

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo  $rowcount; // Result 20 ratings
```

**Ratings**

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo  $row['ratting'];// 1.0 2.0 4.0.......

                    ?>
```

**My problem how can I calculate the total average**

```
  example like a total average of 4.3
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this all in MySQL:

`SELECT to_user_id, COUNT(rating) AS total_ratings, AVG(rating) AS average_rating
FROM rating
WHERE to_user_id = 123
GROUP BY to_user_id`

`echo "{$row['to_user_id']} has an average rating of {$row['average_rating']} from a total of {$row['total_ratings']} rating(s)";`

Answer (score 0):

consider using mysql AVG function and group by user

`SELECT AVG(rating) _avg from ratings group by user;`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp

Comment: results getting empty

Comment: That's not possible. AVG is an aggregator function. AS long as the SQL is correct, it will return data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$average = array_sum($row['ratting']) / count($row['ratting']);

print_r($average);
```

Comment: getting results like this   306 
305.71428571429 
305.71428571429 
305.85714285714 
305.14285714286 
305.42857142857 
306.28571428571 
306.28571428571 
306.57142857143 
306.85714285714 
300.28571428571 
300.42857142857 
307.28571428571 
307.42857142857 
332.85714285714 
333.14285714286

Comment: Ah sorry, you must get the data from the `ratting`, not the row

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (sum(ratting)/count(ratting)) as average FROM rating ;

add the scores and count them, the rest takes care of SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can be use this:-

```
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT AVG(rating) as average_rating FROM rating where to_user_id='".userid."'");
```